# Android Emulator inside a Windows VM in QubesOS

Tags: windows, android, vmware, qubes-os

Does anyone know if it's possible to run a Android Emulator inside a Windows VM in QubesOS? A short answer is very good but I will be very glad if someone can help me through the process. Or maybe I can run Android another way in QubesOS?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What emulator are you using? Where are you experiencing problems?

Answer (score 2):

As of today (2019-07-10), Qubes OS latest version (4.0.1) doesn't support nested virtualization (Intel VT-x, SVM, etc...) which is needed for a usable Android Emulator.

You can find more about this in the Qubes OS related issue here: https://github.com/QubesOS/qubes-issues/issues/4104

I've replied to this issue w.r.t the Android emulator and you can find my reply here: https://github.com/QubesOS/qubes-issues/issues/4104#issuecomment-510036475